# Analog of OpenCV imdecode() in ITK

Tags: image, opencv, decode, dicom, itk

I use both OpenCV and ITK. I'm wondering if ITK can decode a medical image from a buffer, like OpenCV can, with `cv::imdecode()`. For example, if I have a DICOM file read into a buffer `buf` using `fread()`, is there an API in ITK that I can use to get an `itk::Image` from `buf`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

ITK has an IO mechanism to determine file type based on its extension, and use the appropriate `ImageIO` class to do the actual reading. The `ImageIO` interface is uniform. A simple example is one for [NRRD](https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/ITK/blob/master/Modules/IO/NRRD/include/itkNrrdImageIO.h), and more complicated one is [GDCM](https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/ITK/blob/master/Modules/IO/GDCM/include/itkGDCMImageIO.h).

The simple workaround is to write that buffer into a [file in temp folder](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/tmpnam), and then read it using regular IO mechanism.

Comment: Thanks! The reason I need this is because I'm using ITK in a distributed environment, where one node can send a compressed image to another over a network. I need to avoid file I/O, unfortunately. Sounds like the only solution I have is to send a decoded image and it's metadata over the network.